# Get Date pattern from date string in JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been searching for a library in JS where I get the output as date format pattern ('yyyy-mm-dd' or 'dd-mm-yyyy' or so on..) from a date as input. the date could be in string format or UNIX.
i.e if we paas date in some dateFormat('2021-08-14') function then output would be yyyy-mm-dd or so on.

If anyone has any idea about this then please let me know I know I can achieve this with regex but I want a build library in JS.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Just use this library: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

momentjs was the most popular for this but is no longer maintained, https://day.js.org/ or  https://date-fns.org/ are good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The Date prototype has a good function for this: [Date.prototype.toDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)
If you create an instance of Date, then you can call toDateString on it, and you have your